# Serve resources from a consistent URL

Tags: magento-1, image, catalog-optimize

I'm working on optimizing our website & am getting this notice when using [GTMetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/).

> The following resources have identical contents, but are served from
>   different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 2
>   request(s) and 10.9KiB.

Now, I can see from the URL that the issue is that 3 of our products have the exact same image, yet Magento has to reference these URLs differently. Is there any way that I can resolve this? I've done some digging using Google but nothing promising has come up.

Fewer requests means faster rendering time & improved efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I was looking for, a method for Magento to reference the same image between different products thus saving disk space & bandwidth and in turn speeding up your site.

[Magento use images on multiple Products](http://www.pixelpaul.net/magento-share-images-on-more-products/)

The extension is free to boot :)

Comment: please check the URL give 404.

Answer (score 0):

This is an edge case where you uploaded the same image to 3 products and those images are stored in different folders. That is why you have 3 different URLs and the same image.

Comment: I realize that, but this is no solution. If GTMetrix can detect that the content is identical, Magento should be able to & reference images more efficiently.

Comment: Yeah, i don’t agree. There is no actual solution since this is not a bug in the core but a justified feature.