# Serve resources from a consistent URL - 2 images URL for single product, same image

Tags: magento2, product-images

I have one image for all three small, base and thumnail.

However, when I am uploading a product , and selecting three options, magento automatically takes this as 2 image URLS in 2 different folder for a single product upload.

Can anyone advise how to assign single image URL in magento for a product.

Below is the URLs for single product upload
For ex: http://www.akkoda.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/300x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/A/K/xAK102.jpg.pagespeed.ic.a5_c7F3nFd.jpg

http://www.akkoda.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/300x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/A/K/xAK102.jpg.pagespeed.ic.a5_c7F3nFd.jpg

Comment: Magento is resizing the different sizes (small, thumbnail, ...) as a form of cache instead of always showing the full image and let the browser resize it on screen. It is normal for any webshop to do this in this way to reduce file transfer sizes. The obvious side effect is that you would have multiple image URL's, one for every size...

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but when I am checking my webpage speed in GT metrix. it shows only few images needs to Serve resources from a consistent URL which means how others product are not shown in that report. I am bit confused how to overcome this "Serve resources from a consistent URL"

Comment: Please check the answer on this page http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31137/serve-resources-from-a-consistent-url

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears when you have a product with only one image assigned to all placeholders (thumbnail, small image, base image) and you call two of that images to switch when hovering with the mouse. 
An easy fix would be to have at least two different images per product assigned to different placeholders. 
The not so easy fix is to edit the phtml files that load the product images in catalog view, determine if the product has just one image and then load only once if that's the case.